# Trouble creating default constructor

Tags: android

**Edit: @spiderman Thank you for your effort. I've fixed the error message by addressing what I did in my last comment (about the tutorial using the class as a custom view) so I think I will be fine.**

Android gave me a no zero constructor error so I am now trying to write a default constructor as follows:

```
public SignatureActivity() {
    super("SignatureActivity");
}
```

But I am getting an error telling me I can't put a view object in as a string - View in View cannot be applied to java.lang.String.

How can I fix this to be able to run my code successfully?

Here is the class:

```
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;





public class SignatureActivity extends View {

public SignatureActivity() {
    super("SignatureActivity");
}



private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

public SignatureActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    Log.v("SignatureActivity", "This is onTouchEvent");

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Set a new starting point
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Connect the points
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    // Makes our view repaint and call onDraw
    invalidate();
    return true;
}


/**@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signature);



} */



/**@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_signature, menu);
    return true;
}*/

/**@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}*/




}
```

Comment: When you write your default constructor, why don't you simply call the `super()` instead of calling `super("SignatureActivity");` ?

Comment: Well if I just put super(); instead of super("SignatureActivity"); it says cannot resolve method super(). I would do anything that is correct, I'm just right now following a tutorial which uses super("SignatureActivity").

Comment: Updated inline comments in answer

Comment: Alex, I had to remove my answer as I felt it's helpless. Good to see you are doing good now.